# How to manage these "pretty" URLs - nginx rewrite or PHP REQUEST_URI parsing?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I've decided on the following URL scheme for some pages on my site:

```
https://www.example.com/photos/years2014,2015,2016/
https://www.example.com/photos/years2016/
https://www.example.com/photos/events123,234/
```

It's trivial to make sure all of those URIs end up at photos.php, but what'd be the best way to convert the "QS" part into useful PHP variables?  My webserver is nginx but given that I'd need to rewrite the top example to

```
?years[]=2014&years[]=2015&years[]=2016
```

I'm not sure rewriting is feasible?

So should I just dissect $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and extract the values I want from there?

E.g. something along these lines:

```
function fetchPretty(string $var, string $default=''): string
{
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $search = '/'.$var;
    $posStart = mb_strpos($uri, $search);

    if ($posStart) {
        $posStart += mb_strlen($search);
        $posEnd = mb_strpos($uri, '/', $posStart);

        if ($posEnd) {
            return mb_substr($uri, $posStart, $posEnd - $posStart);
        }
    }
    return $default;
}
```